# How to pass an environment file .env in a production environment via an ".env" file?

Tags: python, flask, production-environment

I am currently playing around with Python Flask. I am trying to understand the configuration of environment variables better. I know how to pass environment variables to my code when in development environment. On one hand, there is the '.flaskenv' which is for non-critical variables that is okay to have tracked by the version control but there are also the '.env' file where sensitive data is to be put. This data will differ based on the enviornment. In development I will use one database and in production it will be a different one. I have put the '.env' file in my gitignore file thus it is not being pushed to git. I want to be able to pass a similar file in production to my app.

So, I have an "**init**.py" file where I have an application factory function that makes global app variable very useful. I can create multiple apps with different configurations.

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
import os

from src.blog import bp as blog_bp


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    app.register_blueprint(blog_bp)
    
    return app
```

I use "os.environ", to get the variables from the local development .env file which is in the folder of my project. The problem I have is that I don't know where to store a production .env file and how to access it?

I thought of GitHub Actions, where I pass the environment variable FLASK_ENV, but I do not know if this is the way for many variables with sensitive data in a file.

Comment: _"I want to be able to pass a similar file in production to my app."_ - the point of `.env` files is to _simulate_, for local development (where you might have multiple different projects on your machine) the production environment. In the production environment, set _actual environment variables_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi, thank for the reply. Yes, it is clear to me that the .env is for local simulation but I still need to fine a way to pass environment variables in production environment and I don't know how to do this. I prefer to do it if possible with some kind of a file which I pass to my app but how?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your production environment is set. Is it a k8s deployment? You can mount a file with the secrets inside the pods. Also, depending on the cloud provider you are using you will have different storage options for your sensitive variables.

> I thought of GitHub Actions, where I pass the environment variable FLASK_ENV, but I do not know if this is the way for many variables with sensitive data in a file

Well, since you mentioned it, I see no problem in using GitHub Actions for that purpose. Actually, under the repository **Settings > Security > Secrets and variables > Actions** you can create secrets which you can call in your workflows. These are special variables that GitHub Actions does not allow to be outputted.

You can call them inside your workflow steps with the following syntax:

```
steps:
   - name: some-service-login
     run: |
       some-service-cli login --username ${{ secrets.SERVICE_LOGIN }} --password ${{ secrets.SERVICE_PASSWORD }}
```